# Why is my app only building the arm64 slice?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, app-store, arm64

My iOS app has the following build settings:

[image]

And yet when I attempt submit the app to the store, I receive this error:

[image]

If I add arm64 to UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities as the error suggests, I get the following message upon submission:

[image]

Why did the first archive only contain the arm64 slice?

My project does contain a couple other projects (RestKit and CocoaTouchBarcodes), but these projects' build settings look the same as mine. My project also links to the Google Analytics library. I have verified that it is the latest version.

What could be causing my problem?

Comment: Is there any difference between your project build settings and your target build settings?

Comment: Nope, no difference in the build settings

Comment: When you look at the build log, do you see one architecture being built or both?  (Trying to understand whether it's really a build problem or a submission problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had my AppStore Valid Architectures for the project, not target, set to "armv7, arm64". The problem is that comma in there. I must have added it while entering architectures manually at some point. After removing the comma, the armv7 slice builds and the app store submission succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue for tvOS application submit, what helped me was to add this to all cocoapods and frameworks plists:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>arm64</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a device plugged in?

-If you have a device plugged in, that device's architecture is the ACTIVE ARCHITECTURE, so you need to unplug the device.

Also try;

-Set "Build Active Architecture Only" to NO for targets and project.

Comment: I get the same error message regardless of whether I have a device plugged in. "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to NO.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging search I could understand:

1. "... the presence of a given key indicates the corresponding feature is required"
2. ".. omitting a key indicates that the feature is not required but that the app is able to run if the feature is present"

So, if you put `armv7` it's the same as `only armv7 devices can run it`. Probably in a previous version of your app you supported all devices. So just remove the key `armv7` and your app will be able to support all kind of devices (armv7 and arm64).

- Pay attention to supported architectures